# pandas: read csv filtering columns by old name and renaming them at the same time

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to read only specific columns from the csv and rename the columns in one go. Is it possible? If I use `names` and `usecols` than `usecols` already expects new names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use positional indexing in `usecols`, so if you know the positions in your file you could do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", usecols=[2,6], names=["two", "six"])
```

Comment: That's the best I got to as well - what I wanted is to refer to the old names in usecols and then rename them. I guess it's not possible and you need to rename as a separate step. fair enough